# Prove n cycles of length n is the identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

If $\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}  1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n  \end{pmatrix}$, show that $\sigma^n=\varepsilon$ and that $n$ is the smallest positive integer with this property.

This is obviously true,

$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n\end{pmatrix}\cdots\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n\end{pmatrix}$

I was thinking that looking at $\sigma$ as function of $x$ like $f(x)=\begin{cases}x+1 & 0<x<n \\ 1 & x=n\end{cases}$

Then $f(\dots f(f(f(x))))$ $n$ times would be $x+n$, which I think is the right direction. However, I don't know how to define the function correctly so that this actually makes sense.

Comment: You can define the function $x\mapsto x+1$ mod $n$. Then you are actually working in the group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Excellent!! Huge "I should've thought of that" moment, Thank you!